# Implementation issues with SSO

Tags: php, single-sign-on, cas

Let me preface this by saying I'm a beginner in a PHP environment so there may be a simple answer here. We're trying to use phpCAS to connect to our university's CAS server.

Our server has been set up to match these requirements: http://www.ja-sig.org/wiki/display/CASC/phpCAS+requirements, and we have installed phpCAS to it's own accessable directory & included its path in the "include_path" variable so it can be easily accessed.

When running the [/CAS-1.0.1/docs/examples/example_simple.php](http://www.ja-sig.org/wiki/display/CASC/phpCAS+examples) that comes with the install, i receive the following warnings over and over:

> Warning: error_log() [function.error-log]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp/phpCAS.log) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/) in /var/www/html/root/CAS-1.0.1/CAS.php on line 453
>
> Warning: error_log(/tmp/phpCAS.log) [function.error-log]: failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in /var/www/html/root/CAS-1.0.1/CAS.php on line 453

I get these warnings repeated over and over on the screen, followed by this message:

> CAS Authentication wanted!
>   You should already have been redirected to the CAS server. Click here to continue.

Clicking the login sends me to our appropriate cas server, then redirects me straight back to this page, with all the warnings still visible. Any thoughts?

Comment: It looks like your PHP installation is running in safe mode, hence the open_basedir error message. Is there a phpCAS option you can set to write the log file inside of /var/www somewhere? That would at least allow you to see the log output.

Comment: Phill- you're correct! This stopped the warnings from happening, and now I can see the error log. I'll update the question above to show the log.

Answer (score 1):

Your CAS implementation wants to write a log to a the `/tmp` directory, but your PHP configuration prohibits that.  To open that directory for the script, try either

```
open_basedir = /var/www/:/tmp/
```

in your `php.ini` configuration file, or

```
php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/:/tmp/"
```

in your `httpd.conf` (if applicable).